# Teradata Editdistance function

Tags: teradata

I am trying to use the teradata editdistance function, and it works nicely in the case I have static strings, e.g. **select editdistance('Hello','Hella');**

If I then introduce a column into the first string, that also works nicely e.g.
**select editdistance(First_Name1, 'Hello');**

But I do not seem to be able to understand how to do it over multiple strings for each input e.g.
**select editdistance(First_Name1, First_Name2);**

If I was using python a for loop would do the trick but that is not an option for this data unfortunately.

| First_Name1 | First_Name2 |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Adom |
| Chris | Chriss |
| Jane | Ben |

Comment: You have to logically have the two columns in the same row of a relation to apply the function. For example, if First_Name1 comes from Table1 and First_Name2 comes from Table2, and you want to compare every First_Name1 with every First_Name2, that would require a CROSS JOIN  between Table1 and Table2.

Comment: That has worked brilliantly, thank you for your response.

Comment: @Fred, please put your comment up as an answer, then rorymck should accept is as an answer. you deserve the acknowledgement :-)